# LWJGL program not running properly after writing along a tutorial

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm writing a Tetris game using LWJGL and I'm using this tutorial https://coffeebeancode.gitbook.io/lwjgl-game-design/ . However, my code doesn't run properly. It doesn't show a triangle as expected after showing a window with black background. Here is the code:

```java
package io.onion27.a_minecraft_mod.tetris;

import io.onion27.a_minecraft_mod.tetris.render.Mesh;
import io.onion27.a_minecraft_mod.tetris.render.MeshLoader;
import io.onion27.a_minecraft_mod.tetris.util.Platform;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.system.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Tetris {

    long mainWindow;

    Tetris() {
        System.out.println("Tetris object constructed");
    }

    public void run() {
        init();
        loop();
        glfwFreeCallbacks(mainWindow);
        glfwDestroyWindow(mainWindow);

        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
        // will print the error message in System.err.
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
        if ( !glfwInit() )
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

        // Configure GLFW
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable
        if (Platform.isMacOS()) {
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
        }

        // Create the window
        mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(856, 482, "MineTetris", NULL, NULL);
        if ( mainWindow == NULL )
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

        // Get the thread stack and push a new frame
        try ( MemoryStack stack = stackPush() ) {
            IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
            IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*

            // Get the window size passed to glfwCreateWindow
            glfwGetWindowSize(mainWindow, pWidth, pHeight);

            // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
            GLFWVidMode vidmode = Objects.requireNonNull(glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor()));

            // Center the window
            glfwSetWindowPos(
                    mainWindow,
                    (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                    (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
            );
        } // the stack frame is popped automatically

        // Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(mainWindow);
        // Enable v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(mainWindow, this::onWindowsResize);
        glfwSetKeyCallback(mainWindow, this::onKey);

        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(mainWindow);
    }

    void onWindowsResize(long windowHnd, int width, int height) {
        System.out.printf("(%d, %d)%n", width, height);
    }

    void onKey(long windowHnd, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
        if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(windowHnd, true);
    }

    private void loop() {
        // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
        // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
        // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
        // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
        // bindings available for use.
        GL.createCapabilities();
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(mainWindow);

        // Set the clear color
//        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        // FIXME test code
        float[] vertices = {
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
                0f, 0.5f, 0f
        };

        int[] indices = {0, 1, 2};
        Mesh meshTriangle = MeshLoader.createMesh(vertices, indices);

        // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
        // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
        while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose(mainWindow) ) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

            glBindVertexArray(meshTriangle.getVaoID());
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, meshTriangle.getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glBindVertexArray(0);

            glfwSwapBuffers(mainWindow);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

where the source code of `MeshLoader` is exactly the same as the tutorial.

Edit:
`MeshLoader.java`:

```java
package io.onion27.a_minecraft_mod.tetris.render;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MeshLoader {
    public static List<Integer> vaos = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<Integer> vbos = new ArrayList<>();

    private static FloatBuffer createFloatBuffer(float[] data) {
        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
        buffer.put(data);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }

    private static IntBuffer createIntBuffer(int[] data) {
        IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(data.length);
        buffer.put(data);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }

    private static void storeData(int attribute, int dimensions, float[] data) {
        int vbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        vbos.add(vbo);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        FloatBuffer buffer = createFloatBuffer(data);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(attribute, dimensions, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    private static void bindIndices(int[] data) {
        int vbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        vbos.add(vbo);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        IntBuffer buffer = createIntBuffer(data);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    public static Mesh createMesh(float[] positions, int[] indices) {
        int vao = genVAO();
        storeData(0, 3, positions);
        bindIndices(indices);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        return new Mesh(vao, indices.length);
    }

    private static int genVAO() {
        int vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        vaos.add(vao);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
        return vao;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).